# GridView HeaderRow.TableSection error

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a bad error when setting GridViews HeaderRow.TableSection to TableRowSection.TableHeader: The table  must contain row sections in order of header, body, then footer. 
Please, note, that I do it in grids DataBound event handler and I do NOT use paging. How can it be?

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you should set type of the first row to header when it will created :

```
protected void GridView1_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowIndex == 0)
    {
        e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.Header;

    }
}
```

Now You Can Do this :

```
    GridView1.DataSource = dt;
    GridView1.DataBind();
    GridView1.HeaderRow.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableHeader;
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I had some rows dynamically inserted to the header and they didn't have RowType == DataControlRowType.Header

Answer (score 0):

`GridView` add tag `ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="true"`:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" class="table table-striped table-bordered" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="true" >
```