# Exception while binding jQuery datatable to gridview

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, gridview, datatables

I am trying to bind jquery datatable to gridview. It throws exception.

"The table  must contain row sections in order of header, body, then footer. "

### Steps

### 1) JavaScript call

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
/* Define two custom functions (asc and desc) for string sorting */
  $(document).ready(function () {
    /* Build the DataTable with third column using our custom sort functions */
    $('#gvInitiavtives').dataTable({
        "aaSorting": [[0, 'asc']          
    });
});
```

### 2) Gridview

```
 <asp:GridView ID="gvInitiavtives" runat="server" Width="100%" CssClass="Grid" 
                     RowStyle-Width="30px" AutoGenerateColumns="false" HeaderStyle-CssClass="GridHeader"  RowStyle-CssClass="GridItem" AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="GridAltItem"  DataKeyNames="InitiativeIdx" AllowSorting="true" ClientIDMode="Static" >
                <EmptyDataRowStyle BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="0px" />
                <EmptyDataTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblNorecId" runat="server" Text="Sorry! Your requested records are not found, please try with other search criteria." Font-Bold="true" ForeColor="red" Font-Names="Arial" Font-Size="small"></asp:Label>
                </EmptyDataTemplate>
                <Columns>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="BusinessUnit" HeaderText="" HeaderStyle-Wrap="false" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="NotSet" SortExpression="BusinessUnit" />
                    <asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>

                    <asp:Label ID="lblInitiaiveName" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("InitiativeName") %>' ToolTip ='<%# String.Format("{0} ; {1}",Eval("Initiative"), Eval("InitiativeDescription")) %>' ></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
---
---
</Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
```

### 3) code behind

```
protected void Page_PreRender(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    // support for jquery datatables
    if (gvInitiavtives.Rows.Count > 0) {
        gvInitiavtives.UseAccessibleHeader = true;
        gvInitiavtives.HeaderRow.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableHeader;
    }

}
```

### 4) Exception

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

The table  must contain row sections in order of header, body, then footer. 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.Web.HttpException: The table  must contain row sections in order of header, body, then footer.

Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.  

Stack Trace: 


[HttpException (0x80004005): The table  must contain row sections in order of header, body, then footer.]
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Table.RenderContents(HtmlTextWriter writer) +8790317
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebControl.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer) +32
```

Comment: +1 for the well formatted question & link might help : http://forums.asp.net/t/1330555.aspx/1

Comment: Try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8200681/apply-jquery-datatables-plugin-to-asp-gridview to Apply Jquery DataTables plugin to ASP GridView

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3544027/720771

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8630967/gridview-headerrow-tablesection-error?answertab=oldest#tab-top

Comment: Ronak is right, I had the same error in the same circumstances, and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/431413/gridview-with-pager-topandbottom/3544027#3544027 fixed it.  I've encouraged the author to cross-post it here.

Answer (score 0):

Change  code like this

```
$('[id*=gvInitiavtives]').prepend($("<thead></thead>").append($(this).find("[id*=gvInitiavtives] tr:first"))).dataTable({
"aaSorting": [[0, 'asc']          
    });
```